# PLT track in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, gps, import

What are the best practices for importing and aggregating tracks (in my case in 'plt' format) in a PostGIS table, grouped by user. Are there any tools/db models/tutorials available?

Answer (score 4):

Hallo

PLT format I don't know.

but to aggregate the points to lines when you have it in PostGIS is easy.
use [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_MakeLine.html)

```
CREATE TABLE tracklines as
SELECT ST_MakeLine(the_geom) as the_geom FROM 
(SELECT * FROM trackpoints ORDER BY timestamp) a GROUP BY user;
```

/Nicklas

Comment: +1 Thanks, that will be really useful after I have imported the points. Since I suppose importing gps tracks is a quite common task I was wondering if there were any tools to automate it. The format may not be a major issue, it can certainly be converted to something else. Google earth can convert them to kml/z easily. Thanks for any additional pointers.